Is there a way to change the slope of a data set?
I have the next data frame with the activity of some cells measured with emitted fluorescence. As fluorescence increases, so the activity of the cell does. I wonder if there is a way to change the slope of every column
Traces <- structure(list(Time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 
76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 
92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99), C000 = c(0.007745947, 0.00856473, 
0.008598101, 0.008522989, 0.008529876, 0.008465133, 0.008586565, 
0.008222776, 0.007942568, 0.007954289, 0.007575975, 0.007877418, 
0.007271874, 0.007494519, 0.007290578, 0.007285975, 0.007357418, 
0.007102786, 0.007119637, 0.006916186, 0.00694334, 0.00698516, 
0.007318676, 0.007445516, 0.007293478, 0.007129741, 0.007388188, 
0.007370884, 0.007383739, 0.007398436, 0.007462119, 0.007165095, 
0.007157743, 0.007166557, 0.006991819, 0.007039736, 0.00701218, 
0.006749405, 0.00666279, 0.006871449, 0.006662289, 0.006371251, 
0.006511123, 0.006474687, 0.006277116, 0.006588584, 0.006364191, 
0.006377538, 0.00662436, 0.00654058, 0.006906729, 0.00703144, 
0.006936092, 0.006690061, 0.006736763, 0.006568566, 0.006576183, 
0.006757781, 0.006784108, 0.00651679, 0.006624643, 0.006763031, 
0.006274159, 0.006366617, 0.006490008, 0.006393296, 0.006324633, 
0.006443507, 0.006205258, 0.006552782, 0.006465735, 0.006582045, 
0.006547137, 0.006496394, 0.006413003, 0.006281714, 0.006418668, 
0.00685453, 0.006768875, 0.006601905, 0.006523658, 0.006554539, 
0.006779726, 0.006519909, 0.006628941, 0.00697579, 0.006502145, 
0.006442713, 0.006471944, 0.006478918, 0.006383191, 0.006854261, 
0.006925842, 0.006582496, 0.006443107, 0.006688309, 0.006952146, 
0.006195122, 0.005986007, 0.005754372), C001 = c(0.005956991, 
0.006171418, 0.006320661, 0.006222759, 0.006334484, 0.006454936, 
0.006248961, 0.006399971, 0.006254959, 0.006456097, 0.006589501, 
0.006539846, 0.006470903, 0.006595305, 0.006458043, 0.006340127, 
0.006373045, 0.006120836, 0.006057614, 0.006039695, 0.005795198, 
0.0056458, 0.005765721, 0.005879726, 0.005730799, 0.005740636, 
0.005656463, 0.005679734, 0.005652355, 0.005649901, 0.005633659, 
0.005384896, 0.005457792, 0.005490016, 0.005483489, 0.005460892, 
0.005391839, 0.005403838, 0.005570064, 0.005674303, 0.005455717, 
0.005418216, 0.005493078, 0.005573068, 0.005561324, 0.005394568, 
0.005492466, 0.00547233, 0.005709499, 0.005533796, 0.00545156, 
0.00562649, 0.005458904, 0.005471815, 0.005586516, 0.005511847, 
0.005518293, 0.005636208, 0.005585385, 0.005469498, 0.005513798, 
0.005455469, 0.005363267, 0.005510833, 0.005492831, 0.005504732, 
0.005531432, 0.005394782, 0.005432344, 0.00539179, 0.005415278, 
0.005247213, 0.005295684, 0.005290083, 0.005245278, 0.005366738, 
0.005395874, 0.005238843, 0.005358493, 0.005255845, 0.005336578, 
0.005445765, 0.005450137, 0.005478496, 0.005460055, 0.005535314, 
0.005324707, 0.005300689, 0.005402509, 0.005190141, 0.005250184, 
0.005362611, 0.005355681, 0.005472326, 0.005359346, 0.005312607, 
0.005221206, 0.005306058, 0.005215725, 0.005526785), C002 = c(0.007552462, 
0.007984676, 0.007980356, 0.008244213, 0.008093463, 0.008223756, 
0.008268585, 0.007930938, 0.007839961, 0.007450575, 0.007415346, 
0.007565133, 0.007247118, 0.00721564, 0.007284995, 0.007216053, 
0.007264559, 0.007168394, 0.007196189, 0.007023979, 0.006598721, 
0.006896422, 0.006740974, 0.006725017, 0.006678152, 0.006677107, 
0.006769371, 0.006630402, 0.006624777, 0.006496541, 0.006404278, 
0.0063259, 0.00628389, 0.006338084, 0.006263914, 0.006267926, 
0.006308224, 0.006409625, 0.006105127, 0.00631443, 0.006241651, 
0.006005661, 0.006142643, 0.006172415, 0.006047851, 0.006016528, 
0.005951286, 0.006186087, 0.006270413, 0.006138917, 0.005935804, 
0.005991005, 0.006009258, 0.006039776, 0.006213999, 0.006289921, 
0.006156805, 0.006371458, 0.006324609, 0.006402395, 0.006364633, 
0.006623463, 0.006517728, 0.006579295, 0.006425389, 0.006306021, 
0.00628629, 0.006263034, 0.006016364, 0.005820274, 0.005793911, 
0.006063862, 0.00612715, 0.00606108, 0.006142704, 0.006156606, 
0.006183207, 0.006202525, 0.006189455, 0.006371587, 0.006298558, 
0.006203577, 0.006307225, 0.006304522, 0.006166814, 0.006436977, 
0.00623723, 0.006289181, 0.006394646, 0.006376448, 0.006309251, 
0.006529837, 0.006640962, 0.006383372, 0.006407166, 0.006540346, 
0.006733898, 0.006969205, 0.007460937, 0.007348643), C003 = c(0.007114264, 
0.008686776, 0.009388296, 0.00905965, 0.008706064, 0.008849876, 
0.008620242, 0.008120851, 0.008050356, 0.008147282, 0.008146336, 
0.008403327, 0.008206969, 0.008121977, 0.008037858, 0.008157532, 
0.008161583, 0.007731189, 0.007801163, 0.008271939, 0.007942918, 
0.008461234, 0.0080913, 0.007993557, 0.007944861, 0.008241849, 
0.008489931, 0.008410476, 0.00837615, 0.008398232, 0.008000773, 
0.007633297, 0.00770339, 0.007955562, 0.007486511, 0.007476098, 
0.007646249, 0.007557975, 0.007126491, 0.00747163, 0.007470205, 
0.007075914, 0.006964429, 0.006887827, 0.006899905, 0.007056713, 
0.007066121, 0.00710769, 0.006885062, 0.006865994, 0.007212111, 
0.007241881, 0.00700955, 0.006722624, 0.006616993, 0.006698722, 
0.006859245, 0.007452228, 0.007299629, 0.007238532, 0.007382048, 
0.008048941, 0.00763573, 0.007451576, 0.006843455, 0.006563839, 
0.006011556, 0.006126467, 0.005687437, 0.005745339, 0.005858997, 
0.005824937, 0.006089481, 0.006022337, 0.005734494, 0.005923385, 
0.005939743, 0.005916969, 0.005865533, 0.006010748, 0.006296819, 
0.006492103, 0.006325565, 0.006081958, 0.006056441, 0.006218916, 
0.005749296, 0.005538785, 0.005658634, 0.005799723, 0.005969279, 
0.006249565, 0.006423372, 0.006001107, 0.005823527, 0.005869108, 
0.006789205, 0.007041554, 0.007266665, 0.007552045)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

As you can see, the slope of every column (cell) goes down over time, and the values at the beginning are higher than the values at the end, but that is not physiologically possible, I think most of it is noise. So, I would like to know if there is a way to adjust the data to a more straight slope and closer to zero, if that is possible.
Traces %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("C"), names_to = "Cell", values_to = "deltaF") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = deltaF, color = Cell))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)


It sounds like you just want to keep the residuals against the regression lines?

Or it sounds like you want to normalize it, but I'd go with @JonSpring.

Usually, to de-trend time series, i.e. to make it stationary, we differentiate.
> Traces_d <- matrixStats::colDiffs(as.matrix(Traces[-1]))
> 
> par(mar=c(3, 4, 2, 2), mfrow=c(1, 2))
> matplot(Traces[-1], type='l')
> matplot(Traces_d, type='l')
> abline(h=0)



Here's an approach that uses nested data to regress each Cell separately and to calculate residuals against those linear regressions. (lm(deltaF ~ Time, ... calculates the linear regression of deltaF on Time, giving us the linear trend. The residuals are the difference between the actual data and that trend, i.e. the data with all slope and offset from 0 ("intercept") removed. That's why we're left with geom_smooth lines that stay at y = 0.
library(tidyverse)
Traces %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("C"), names_to = "Cell", values_to = "deltaF") %>% 

  nest(-Cell) |>
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(deltaF ~ Time, data = .x)),
         tidied = map(fit, broom::augment)) |>
  unnest(tidied) |>
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = .resid, color = Cell))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)



It looks like what I am looking for. Could you elaborate on the process a little bit more please? At the end would I be working with the residuals of my data?

@LuisAngel This is called detrending the data, a very useful way to see patterns. Google "detrend" for more information.

get it, thank you all!
